# NavigationItem leftNavigationItem is not clickable

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

I am having MasterViewController and it has childView as UITabBarController. UITabBarController has navigationcontroller as tab bar item. Both MasterViewController and TabBarItem ViewController extends from BaseViewController. I have written code to add leftNavigationItem(UIBarButtonItem) on BaseViewController viewDidLoad method. But leftNavigationItem(UIBarButtonItem) is not clickable. I have added selector to the leftnavigationItem(UIBarButtonItem) as well.

MasterViewController

```
class MasterViewController: BaseViewController {
    // MARK: Outlets
    var masterTabBarController: UITabBarController!

    // MARK: View Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initializeView()
    }
    
    // MARK: Overridden Methods
    override func initializeView() {
        super.initializeView()
        addTabBar()
    }
    
    // MARK: Private Methods
    private func addTabBar() {
        guard let appTabBarController = AppRouter.appTabBarController
            else {
                return
        }
        masterTabBarController = appTabBarController
        addChild(appTabBarController)
        appTabBarController.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(appTabBarController.view)
    }
}
```

TransactionsViewController

```
class TransactionsViewController: BaseViewController {
    // MARK: Outlets
    
    // MARK: View Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initializeView()
    }
    
    // MARK: Overridden Methods
    override func initializeView() {
        super.initializeView()
    }    
}
```

BaseViewController

```
// MARK: -
enum LeftButtonType: Int {
    case site
    case back
}

// MARK: -
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    private var leftButtonType: LeftButtonType = .site
    
    // MARK: View Methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = ColorConstants.white
        addLeftNavigationItem()
    }
    
    // MARK: Action Methods
    @objc func leftNavigationButtonClicked() {
        print("leftNavigationButtonClicked")
        switch leftButtonType {
        case .site:
            AppRouter.presentSiteSelectionViewController(fromViewController: self)
        case .back:
            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Private Methods
    private func addLeftNavigationItem() {
        if navigationController?.viewControllers.count != 1 {
            leftButtonType = .back
        }
        switch leftButtonType {
        case .site:
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(leftNavigationButtonClicked))
        case .back: break
        }
    }
}
```

This is Storyboard

[image]